# OpenCV alternative to MATLAB's rangefilt function

Tags: matlab, opencv

Is there a function in OpenCV which does exactly what [`rangefilt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rangefilt.html) does in MATLAB?

I have gone through the OpenCV [Image Filtering documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html), but could not find something which does what `rangefilt` does. The [`filter2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d) function convolves with a kernel (linear operation) so this does not seem applicable.

Comment: I have already gone through the openCV documentation and could not find something which does what rangefilt does.

Comment: hey,  Aleksander Lidtke is kinda right there, looking at the *known* part won't get you anywhere. still, there might be no such thing in opencv. for a moment i thought : filter2D ? but the max-min definition of your range there does not sound like it's applyable ( you have to *know* the kernel before )

Answer (score 2):

Consider that the [`erode`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#erode) and [`dilate`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#dilate) functions are min and max filters, respectively, when applied to grayscale images.

For example, the following is the equation for erosion in the OpenCV docs:

[image]

and dilation:

[image]

Simply define the neighborhood (`kernel`/`element` in the docs) as you would with a hypothetical range filter, apply `erode` and `dilate` in parallel to your source image `I` to obtain two new images `E` and `D`, and subtract `D-E` to get the range.

In addition to the OpenCV documentation for `erode` and `dilate`, have a look at [this tutorial on erosion and dilation in OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html), which includes sample code [[repo link]](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/raw/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/ImgProc/Morphology_1.cpp). Note that if you do not specify a structuring element, the default is a 3x3 matrix. When creating the structure element with `getStructuringElement`, most likely, the shape you want is `MORPH_RECT`; the anchor point is automatically the center if not specified, conveniently; and you will just need to specify size.

Comment: @Alva I updated the answer with links for the OpenCV erode/dilate tutorial, and some tips regarding the structuring element.

Comment: @Alva Did you manage to get a median filter in OpenCV implemented? If so and it was based on `erode` and `dilate`, I'd be happy to add the details to my answer.